# Validation rule to restrict picklist value for every user but sys admins

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I need to restrict a picklist on accounts. If the account type is Referral Account, the picklist Category shouldn't be changed to Personal Network if the user isn't System Administrator.

The Referral Account type id is 0125e0000007vrlAAA and the System Administrator id is 00e5e000001wmRv.

I've made this validation rule, but it doesn't seem to restrict the creation of a new referral account with the category Personal Network nor the update of the category from an existing referral account to Personal Network:

```
( ISNEW() ||
ISCHANGED(Category__c) ) &&
RecordTypeId =='0125e0000007vrlAAA' &&
ISPICKVAL(Category__c, "Personal Network") &&
$User.ProfileId!='00e5e000001wmRv'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user should never change the value(neither sys admin or any other user) you can restrict that value in the picklist based on RecordType.

And if the scenario is like a user cannot change the value but Sys admin should be able to update on certain scenarios, you can update your validation rule with Profile Name instead of Profile ID(that Id might be the issue, if validation rule had been deployed from sandbox that ID would differ for different environments).
So try using **$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"**

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of validation rules are to ensure correct data is entered in the system. If you want to restrict access to picklist values you should use a combination of profiles and record types. Basically for the given record type only allow a picklist value for the Sys admin profile